# How to get FailureType in fallback method when using @HystrixCommand

Tags: hystrix

I can get Throwable obj in fallback method, but I cannot tell the throwable which is maybe reaching semaphore limit exception(SEMAPHORE_REJECTED)or maybe circuit-break open exception or my defined exception.

Maybe I can determine it by error message, howerver it's clumsy.

Or is there any way to get HystrixCommand obj in fallback method using command key?

Thx a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a method though it's a bit cumbersome.

```
HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerCommandExecutionHook(new HystrixCommandExecutionHook() {// override onXXX method}
```

Perhaps there is a better approach or api.